# Xcode 10.1, trying to create iOS Development certificate: "You already have a current iOS Development certificate or a pending certificate request."

Tags: xcode

We have been doing this practice for a long time and always works fine, except this time:

1) go to developer.apple.com and Revoke one Development certificate (or more)

2) go to XCode 10.1 and create a new iOS Development

and it always works... except this time.. we now revoked 3 certificates and still when I try to create a new iOS Development certificate I get the same error: 
"You already have a current iOS Development certificate or a pending certificate request."

Solution please?

Regards,

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem and was able to fix it with these steps:

1. Go to developer.apple.com and revoke all development certs there.
2. Create a new developer cert.
3. Download it, and drag to Xcode. (I also dragged it to my Keychain Access app.)
4. Go back to Xcode and click Try Again.

Answer (score -1):

Try restarting your xcode. It worked for me.